# Could 'for' be replace by 'with' in 'Most verbs have six inflectional forms, illustrated here for the lexeme...'

Tags: meaning

> Most verbs have six inflectional forms, illustrated here **for** the lexeme **take**:
>
> 1. I *took* her to school.
> 2. He *takes* her to school.
> 3. They *take* her to school.
> 4. I need to *take* her to school.
> 5. We are *taking* her to school.
> 6. They have *taken* her to school.

In the Oxford Dictionary, there is a fixture '[illustrates something with something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/illustrate?q=illustrates)'. Why is 'for' used,not 'with'?

Comment: Come now, Mr. Wang, your sentences contain neither "for" or "with". If you mean the explanatory sentence for 1) and 2), you should say so because as written, your question is very confusing. No, "for" cannot replace "with".

Comment: Yes, you can say "illustrated here **with** the lexeme take."

Comment: If you want to replace for, I'd use "by the lexeme take".

Comment: Both _with_ and _for_ are possible here, but they don't have the same meaning. See TimR's answer.

Comment: @ColinFine Why not be clearer for the OP? What TimR says is precisely what does not fit in the OP's context. The only other preposition that would work and does not change the meaning is "by".

Comment: @Lambie Yes, 'take' is an example for the illustration.

Comment: illustrated with flowers=there are illustrations of flowers, different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In "illustrated with X",  X is that which *illustrates*. In  "illustrated for X",  X is the "beneficiary" of the illustration, that which is *being illustrated*.

For example:

> The chart illustrates the seasonal spike in heating fuel consumption with data from December, January, and February.
>
> The chart illustrates heating oil consumption for the months of December, January, and February.